# Wait all bytes before proceed (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth, dart-pub

In my code I use the flutter_bluetooth_serial library to communicate with a microcontroller.

How can I do to wait that all the bytes arrive before proceeding to the next step of my function?

```
  static download_file() {
   send_data(Costanti.cmd_download_1, 1028); // here I send the command via bluetooth
                                             // 1028 are the number of bytes I expect as answer
    //--- WAIT THE ARRIVE OF ALL BYTES BEFORE PROCCED---------//
    // manipulation of 1028 bytes
       });
```

Function with I send the data

```
  static void send_data(List<int> charCodes, int byte_to_read){
    Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(charCodes);
    Costanti.dati_arrivati = new List<int>(); //------>> array where I accumulate incoming bytes
    Costanti.connection.output.add(bytes); // Sending data
       }
```

Function where I read the incoming bytes

```
  static  stream_read(){
          Costanti.connection.input.listen((datiLetti) {

     // print("${datiLetti.length}");

      for(int i=0; i< datiLetti.length; i++){
        Costanti.dati_arrivati.add(datiLetti[i])
      }

    }).onDone((){
      toast_message("Device no longer connected");
    });
  }
```

Comment: `//------>> array where I accumulate incoming bytes` ? Dont understand. I would think of an arraay where you would prepare some bytes before you send them.

Comment: We dont see you calling stream_read().

Comment: `int byte_to_read` You are not using that parameter. Further i do not undersatand that there would be any bytes to read for a send function.

Comment: Costanti.connection.input.listen in strem_read() is always listening. As soon as a byte arrives is available with the variable "datiLetti".